# How to filter objects using multiple conditions from an array?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm setting up a couple of filters for an invoices table in an Angular component. One is a search input that matches with the property name of an invoice model from an invoices array the other one is a "status" filter from a drop-down select element.

this new filter will only run when the "statusFilter" (ngModel) is not equal to 0, since 0 is the default and means to show all ignoring the status of the invoice. I am successfully able to filter each condition individually but when trying to add both conditions within one filter function the callbackfn always returns false.

Right now, only after enter a value in the search input is when I get true results from the filter.

HTML

```
<select [(ngModel)]="statusFilter" (change)="updateFilter($event)">
  <option [value]="0">Show All</option>
  <option [value]="4">Paid</option>
  <option [value]="1">Outstanding</option>
  <option [value]=8>Cancelled</option>
</select>
....
<label>Search:
 <input (keyup)="updateFilter($event)" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="search by name.." type="search">
</label>
```

Component

```js
export class CompanyInvoicesComponent implements OnInit {
  public isLoading: boolean;
  public limit = 10;
  public temp = [];
  public selected = [];
  public invoice: Invoice;
  public statusFilter: number = 0;
  public rows: Invoice[];

  @ViewChild(DatatableComponent) table: DatatableComponent;


  constructor(
    private _appService: AppService,
    private _invoiceService: InvoiceService,
  ) {

    this._invoiceService.companyInvoices()
      .subscribe( (invoices) => {
        const invoicesArr = [];
        for (const invoice of invoices) {
          invoicesArr.push(new Invoice(invoice, true));
        }

        this.rows = invoicesArr;
        this.temp = [...invoicesArr];
        this._appService.toggleLoading(false);
      });
  }


  updateFilter(event) {
    const val = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
    let temp = this.temp.filter((invoice) => {

      // the type number is lost after value is changed.
      const parsedStatusFilter = parseInt(this.statusFilter.toString(), 10);
      console.log(parsedStatusFilter);
      if (parsedStatusFilter == 0) {
        return (invoice.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1 || !val);
      } else {
        return (parsedStatusFilter == invoice.statusNumber) && (invoice.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1 || !val);
      }
    });

    // update the rows
    this.rows = temp;
    // Whenever the filter changes, always go back to the first page
    this.table.offset = 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use additional property for searched value (from input) to save it while filtering because for filtering the same method is used, and you need to save both `statusFilter` and searched value. Also check for `length` of string in first filter:

Component:

```
statusFilter = 0;
searchingWord = '';

updateFilter(event) {
  const val = this.searchingWord.toLowerCase();
  const parsedStatusFilter = parseInt(this.statusFilter.toString(), 10);

  const temp = this.temp.filter((invoice) => {

    if (parsedStatusFilter == 0) {
      return (!val.length || invoice.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1);
    } else {
      return (parsedStatusFilter == invoice.statusNumber) && (!val.length || invoice.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1);
    }
  });
  // filtered temp
  console.log('temp', temp);
}
```

HTML template:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="statusFilter" (change)="updateFilter($event)">
  <option [value]="0">Show All</option>
  <option [value]="4">Paid</option>
  <option [value]="1">Outstanding</option>
  <option [value]=8>Cancelled</option>
</select>
<label for="search-box">Search:</label>
<input input name="search-box" id="search-box" [(ngModel)]='searchingWord' (keyup)="updateFilter($event)" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="search by name.." type="search">
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-filter-objects-using-multiple-conditions-from-an-array)

Comment: Awesome, you pointed out what I had missed. I hadn't notice that val was probably getting overwritten by the other input. Here was my mistake. `const val = event.target.value.toLowerCase();` I had checked for lenght in the actual code, somehow I omitted it on the question. Thank you!